# connecting to MSSQL DB using SQLAlchemy throwing error type 08001

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I've got this code:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sa:Passw0rd@172.19.201.75/master.db', echo=True)
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE users (
        username VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
        password VARCHAR NOT NULL
    );
    """
)
connection.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?);
    """,
    "foo", "bar"
    )
result = connection.execute("SELECT username FROM users")
for row in result:
    print "username:", row['username']
connection.close()
```

I'm getting this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access
>   denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)') None None

I ran this query on my DB

```
select db_name()
```

and got this O/P

```
1. master
```

Can someone explain what is wrong in my logic?

Comment: Your connection URI uses the database name ``master.db``. Is this the correct name of your database? Do you want to connect to SQL server's ``master`` database (this is probably not a good idea, since it is an internal database for SQL server).

Comment: Also test your connection info (i.e. server IP, username and password) from another client, for instance SQL server management studio.

Comment: I'm just using master db to test the connection.

Comment: OK, but the db name is ``master`` not ``master.db`` as in your db URI.

Comment: Have you checked that 1) Your SQL server is listening for TCP/IP connections 2) SQL server logins are enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the firewall on the server was rejecting my connection. I disabled the Firewall to check the connection and I got the connection. I've to make an exception in the firewall rule to allow the connection to the SQL Server TCP/IP Port.

One can refer to this link for steps to do so http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx